# Erro in Trap of zabbix server

Tags: linux, zabbix, snmptrapd

I created traps in zabbix to send APC error reports, but they are not working, I checked the firewall ports and port 162 upd shows that it is filtered, how do I remove this filter? I'm using Linux Debian

I already tried to release all the ports and it didn't work, I was hoping that the zabbix traps would work